# Spurious dot with xeCJK, TikZ

Tags: xetex, bold, xecjk

I have a very strange problem when using TikZ and xeCJK. I managed to extract this MWE from my original sources:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newCJKfontfamily\hiraganaFont[AutoFakeBold=1]{NanumMyeongjo}
\begin{document}

{\hiraganaFont \textbfる}\tikz{}

\end{document}
```

(the `polyglossia`/`defaultlanguage` is only there to keep xeCJK (I believe) quiet.)

Symptoms:

- Output is `る.` (hiragana, period; the period is set in whatever is the document default font, not the CJK font; when a `Scale` is present in the CJK font definition, the period is unaffected). Expected output is `る`, without the period.
- **The dot stays** when lines are drawn inside the `\tikz{}` command. It would appear to be positioned to the right of the picture origin (i.e., 'inside' the picture).
- **The dot stays** when the `\tikz{}` command is put between `る` and `}`.
- **The dot stays** when the `\tikz{}` command is changed into a `tikzpicture` environment.
- **The dot stays** when exchanging the CJK font.
- **The dot vanishes** when AutoFakeBold is set to `0`.
- **The dot vanishes** when `\textbf` is deleted (or `\bf` for that matter, whatever their difference is).
- **The dot vanishes** as soon as a non-whitespace, non-CJK glyph is put behind the hiragana, be it inside or outside the pair of braces that surrounds the kana.
- I haven't managed to make the dot appear using a custom-defined environment.

Judging from the diagnostics, it would appear that somehow xeCJK's fake boldening feature and TikZ interact in freaking ways.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

(It is not an answer, sorry.)

It's irrelevant to CJK scripts. I guess it's a bug of `fontspec`.

Test this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}[2011/06/07 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.81)]
\usepackage{fontspec}[2013/03/16 v2.3a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX]

\newfontfamily\testfont[FakeBold=1]{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}

{\testfont X}\tikz{}

\end{document}
```

The problem remains.

Maybe you can ask Joseph Wright to have a look at this.